# IE10 Page can't be displayed, other browsers can

Tags: web-services, internet-explorer, ssl, https, windows-server-2012

I started with a problem connecting to a webservice on a remote server [internal] from a custom made program.

We tested the ws from Firefox and Chrome - both latest and it connects instantly. But in IE10 (latest version for windows 2012 not R2) we get a page can't be displayed error:

- Make sure the web address https://remoteserver:9443 is correct.
- Look for the page with your search engine.
- Refresh the page in a few minutes.
- Make sure TLS and SSL protocols are enabled. Go to Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Settings > Security

I think that IE10 and our program are using the same system libraries, and thats the reason both cannot connect to the web service. If i solve the problem with IE i presume that i could connect to the ws from the program.

The url port is custom and OK as other browsers work. IE10 can open HTTPS connection to other remote servers.

I tried:

- flushing DNS setting,
- reinstalling the CA certificate. Certificate is valid in chrome.
- enabling TLS1.0, TLS1.1, TLS1.2, SSLv3 and SSLv2
- telnet to remote server on port 9443 works
- Using developer tool in IE simulated IE 9, IE8, ...
- ping to remote sever works
- nslookup finds the remote server

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome are using the NSS TLS stack while .NET applications and MSIE use Microsofts SChannel. It is hard to say what's really going on without looking at the traffic, so it would be good to get a packet capture suitable for wireshark from the successful (FF/Chrome) and the unsuccessful connection to see the difference. You could publish thus captures to cloudshark.org.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I got the wireshark capture but i dont really know what is going on. The connection betweem the two servers starts but it suddenly stops. (ps. I can send you the link to cloudshark.org privately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of hardening for PCI DSS(securing servers) and the webservice provider not announcing protocols that were enabled was causing the issue.

Moving the server out of PCIDSS policy made the webservice connection function normally.

The changes were displayed only after restarting the server, because of registry modification.

Thanks to @Steffen Ullrich for driving me in the right direction.